# Mongodb query for array property ne null not working

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute a query like: 
`{array.0.property: {$ne: null}}`.
It return nothing even if all documents have this property different from null.
After some tests i noticed that it work using $elemMatch, but i need to query only for the first element of the array.
The first element is to be considered as "Master" where all query should search.
I can't change document "schema".
Anyone know ho to solve this problem?
I'm using Mongodb 3.6.8.
Thanks in advice.

Example query:

```
db.getCollection('tasks').find({'details.0.code': {$ne: null}});
```

Example documents:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "date": 2018-07-17 06:30:00.000Z,
  .....,
  "details": [
     {
       "code": '123',
       "description": 'something',
       "resolutionYear": 2018
     },
     {
       "code": null,
       "description": 'secondary',
       "resolutionYear": 2019
     }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "exam",
  "date": 2018-09-20 09:00:00.000Z,
  .....,
  "details": [
     {
       "code": null,
       "description": 'exam',
       "resolutionYear": null
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your full query as well as some sample documents from your collection?

Comment: `{"array.0.property": {$not: {$type: "null"}}}`

Comment: This work exactly as i needed, thank you.